# Responsive css grid doesn't shrink to one column

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple HTML page with a responsive css grid and an odd behaviour. Here the page:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(220px, 100%), 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: #999999;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: #FC6057;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: #FDA061;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: #01A787;
}

.item-5 {
  background-color: #1BC1A1;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-1"> item-1 </div>
    <div class="item-2"> item-2 </div>
    <div class="item-3"> item-3 </div>
    <div class="item-4"> item-4 </div>
    <div class="item-5"> item-5 </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I shrink the browser it stops with 2 columns. And not as expected to shrink to one column. But when I set the value for `grid-template-columns` to

```
repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(**250px**, 100%), 1fr));
```

it works fine. The same behaviour in Firefox and Chrome. Any idea?

Comment: I tried your Code and it shrinks properly in both cases

Comment: Me too. On both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Also can't reproduce on any of those two. Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: I also see it shrinking down to one column.

Comment: It seems to be the browsers. I can only resize my sample HTML page to a width of 450px in Firefox or 500px in Chrome. Therefore, there is no break to one column if the minimum width of the div is less than half of this value. But as soon as I display a sidebar (history or developer tools) in the browser, then I can make the browser as small as I want.